# PyTorch training with Batches of different lenghts?

Tags: pytorch

Is it possible to train  model with batches that have unequal lenght during an epoch? I am new to pytorch.

Comment: Hello, are you asking whether there is a way to deliberately produces batches of differents sizes (by tweaking the dataloader or something like that) or whether it is a problem to the neural network when batches of different sizes happen during the training ?

Comment: Yes actually both, as I produce hte variable batch in my Sampler. So, Iwonder if and what I need to do, such that a pytorch Model like a neural network, can handle this?

Comment: Yes. Why wouldn't it work? Your model shouldn't depend on the batch size, so you wouldn't have any problems calling your model with a different batch sizes. Remember the batch size is just the size of your input tensor on the first axis.

Comment: I came from Tensroflow/Keras, and ther I think you can only train with a fixed batch size. But I am not sure if this is still true...

Comment: So, I can call in the for loop of the batches my model on different bachtes without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [dataloader documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), you'll see a `drop_last` parameter, which explains that sometimes when the dataset size is not divisible by the batch  size, then you get a last batch of different size. So basically the answer is yes, it is possible, it happens often and it does not affect (too much) the training of a neural network.

However you must a bit careful, some pytorch layers deal poorly with very small batch sizes. For example if you happen to have Batchnorm layers, and if you get a batch of size 1, you'll get errors due to the fact that batchnorm at some point divides by `len(batch)-1`. More generally, training a network that has batchnorms generally require batches of significant sizes, say at least 16 (literature generally aims for 32 or 64). So if you happen to have variable size batches, take the time to check whether your layers have requirement in terms of batch size for optimal training and convergence. But except in particular cases, your network will train anyway, no worries.

As for how to make your batches with custom sizes, I suggest you look at and take inspiration from the pytorch implementation of [dataloader](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py) and [sampler](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/sampler.py). You may want to implement something similar to `BatchSampler` and use the `batch_sampler` argument of `Dataloader`

Answer (score 0):

No. If you're using transformers make sure to pad the inputs so the batch is all the same length.